# What is the longest wavelength ever measured for a Black Body?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, wavelength, cold-atoms

As said in the title, I am curious about the reported measurements for cooled black bodies. Any source is welcome.

I am neither interested in any thought experiment nor in the well-established law of blackbody radiation accentuated on hot bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's the coldest black body ever measured, which would correspond to the longest wavelength, but it *might* be the cosmic microwave background at a peak wavelength of 1.063 mm.  [However, the spectrum of the cosmic microwave background has been measured at least to about 5 mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background).  The cosmic microwave background is the Doppler-shifted remnant of the black body corresponding to the universe about [370,000 years after the Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Lepton_epoch).

Comment: This seems like more of a guess than an answer. Maybe someone has measured radiation from something in a lab cooled to 1 K. Or 1 mK.

Comment: Maybe, but the best anyone can do is point out the longest wavelength black body radiation measurement they know of.

Comment: It would be interesting to calculate the rate of emission of, say, 10 MHz photons from a test tube full of solid helium at 1 degree Kelvin.  I have a feeling those photons would come out v-e-r-y slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmic Microwave Background is the most perfect source of blackbody radiation that exists in nature and has an associated temperature of 2.7K [Source Wikipedia](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/558520/what-is-the-longest-wavelength-ever-measured-for-a-black-body/558525#558525)

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. It didn’t ask about the most perfect source.

Comment: If you have read the question carefully you would have noticed that my answer perfectly fits the requests. It's not for a case that the other answer is about the same topic. The fact that it is the most perfect source of blackbody radiation present in nature is a property that sums up with the fact that is a very well measured radiation "cooled" by gravitational redshift. So, you are wrong, mine was a perfectly legit answer, but if it was incomplete, that's another thing.

Comment: I read the question carefully. Please do not assume that I did not.